# Is there a way to implement Mapbox navigation Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on an Ionic 4 project and I want to use mapbox map for navigation but I am not sure if I can implement navigation on android and IOS.
Is Mapbox Navigation compatible with Ionic?
If yes, can you suggest me the way through which I can implement mapbox navigation in my Ionic project.
I can only find SDK for both Android & iOS but nothing on cross platform technologies.

I have tried implementing Direction API's provided by mapbox and I was successful in implementing routing from point A to point B

What I expect is, to implement mapbox navigation on a cross platform technology like Ionic 4

Comment: I think you will need to reach out to them directly about it.

Comment: @Devnetics I did so, this is what they said, "We're currently not able to support implementations that use third-party hybrid frameworks such as Ionic. We recommend using the latest version of our native Maps SDKs: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/ or https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/ ". Do you have any other solution?

Comment: @BK_Dev Did you find any solution for this? I am also looking for mapbox integration with ionic 5 and capacitor.